# Having trouble generating a mesh in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to generate a mesh using the code below, and have been successful generating a mesh with width and length of one, but any more and I get an error in the console that says

> "Failed setting triangles. Some indices are referencing out of bounds vertices. IndexCount: 24, VertexCount: 9 UnityEngine.Mesh:set_triangles (int[])"

I have done all the math of calculating the triangles on paper, and all of the values are within the length of the vertices array, going from 0 to 8. I don't have any clue what I am doing wrong, or why this error message is getting thrown, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MeshGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{
    Mesh mesh;
    Vector3[] vertices;
    int[] triangles;

    public Mesh GenerateMesh(int mapWidth, int mapHeight)
    {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        vertices = new Vector3[(mapHeight + 1) * (mapWidth + 1)];
        triangles = new int[6 * (mapHeight * mapWidth)];
        int index = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x <= mapHeight; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y <= mapWidth; y++)
            {
                vertices[index] = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
                index += 1;
            }
        }
        int z = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= triangles.Length - 1; i += 6)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            if (z == mapWidth)
            {
                triangles[i] = i + 1;
                triangles[i + 1] = i + 2;
                triangles[i + 2] = i + mapWidth + 3;
                triangles[i + 3] = i + 1;
                triangles[i + 4] = i + mapWidth + 3;
                triangles[i + 5] = i + mapWidth + 2;
                z = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                triangles[i] = i;
                triangles[i + 1] = i + 1;
                triangles[i + 2] = i + mapWidth + 2;
                triangles[i + 3] = i;
                triangles[i + 4] = i + mapWidth + 2;
                triangles[i + 5] = i + mapWidth + 1;
                z++;
            }
        }
        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        return mesh;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you use your debugger, what are the values are in `triangles`? How large is `vertices`? Do any of those values in `triangles` meet or exceed the size of `vertices`

Comment: It's definitely not a unity bug. I clamped the value of the indices using ```for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i++)     
triangles[i] = triangles[i] < vertices.Length ? triangles[i] : vertices.Length - 1;``` to make sure they were within bounds and got no errors and a mesh came out the other end. I would use a debugger like @Ruzihm mentioned to figure out where things are going wrong. You might want to let us know what you're trying to generate.

Comment: If you are using `GenerateMesh(2,2)`, then `vertices` is of size 9. What is assigned to the value of `triangles[8]`? Wouldn't that be larger than the size of `vertices`?

Comment: The thing is, I can generate a triangle with inputs (1,1), but if I try (2,2) or anything higher, it sends the error message. Also, I have done all of the math for a 2 by 2, and all of the indices should be within the range.

Comment: What does your math calculate for the value of `triangles[8]` for inputs (2,2)? What does the debugger show? And for that matter, the value of elements `triangles` with index >9

Comment: I am just attempting to create a flat mesh that can then be used for procedural terrain. I have done this before, following a tutorial a while back, but I wanted to see if I could figure it out on my own this time.

Comment: So I tried debugging triangles[8], and it came up as ten, which is obviously bigger than the max index of 8, so now I just need to figure out why.

Comment: I think I know why, and I think I am doing this completely wrong. Give me a second to see if I can fix it quick.

Comment: @Phoenix2233 If you find an answer, consider [self-answering](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) below :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was I was using the index of the triangle array to calculate the index of the vertex array. Instead, I needed to use a separate variable (a) to calculate the vertex index. The new code is below.

```
        int a = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.Length; i += 6)
        {
            Debug.Log(i);
            if (z == mapWidth)
            {
                triangles[i] = a + 1;
                triangles[i + 1] = a + 2;
                triangles[i + 2] = a + mapWidth + 3;
                triangles[i + 3] = a + 1;
                triangles[i + 4] = a + mapWidth + 3;
                triangles[i + 5] = a + mapWidth + 2;
                z = 1;
                a += 2;
            }
            else
            {
                triangles[i] = a;
                triangles[i + 1] = a + 1;
                triangles[i + 2] = a + mapWidth + 2;
                triangles[i + 3] = a;
                triangles[i + 4] = a + mapWidth + 2;
                triangles[i + 5] = a + mapWidth + 1;
                z++;
                a++;
            }
        }
```